# addsubview the view not clickable

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm adding a view like this

In `AffairesViewController`:

```
func clickChangeColor(nomAffaire : String, idEcoute : String, config : ConfigDto ){

    let changeColorViewController = ChangeColorViewController()
    changeColorViewController.showCustomAlertInView(self.view, message: "", button: "OK")
}
```

In `ChangeColorViewController` :

```
 func showCustomAlertInView(targetView : UIView ,message : String, button : String)
    {
        targetView.addSubview(self.view)
    }
```

but the view `ChangeColorViewController` is not clickable, only the behind is clicked when I click on the view that I add

in the image we can see the result, the problem is that the view that appear (in blue) is not clickable

[image]

Comment: You are adding self.view in self.view? Wait....WHAT?

Comment: clickChangeColor is in another controller

Comment: I don't think this is how you add `self.view` of one VC as subview of `self.view` of another VC. Apple has given us [ContainerViews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) for this purpose

Comment: Also I am assuming that you have implemented some custom UIAlertView so Why are you creating a ViewController? Just subclass it from UIView and add it as subview of `self.view` of the VC you wish to display it on

Comment: no i dont implement a custom alert it is just a class ChangeColorViewController : UIViewController {

that is connected to xib file, and add it with .addsuview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117666/discussion-between-nsnoob-and-tamtoum1987).

Comment: have you checked the userInteractionEnabled property of views? Maybe one of them was set to NO

Comment: this also could happen in case of bad frame sizes. In method `showCustomAlertInView` check the size of the frame of the view you are adding (I'm about `self.view.frame`) if its set to zeros then clicks and touches will not be recognized

Comment: I am not able to understand that what you are exactly trying yo do. first you are calling a method from another view controller then you are adding the parent view of that view controller on some targetview!!! I guess the AffairesViewController is your target view controller. But why you need to do so? can to please explain in detail what exactly you are trying to do? like are you trying to change colour of affairesviewcontroll from the ChangeColorViewController or something else. Please explain your functionality may be after that i can help you out :)

Comment: i just add a viewcontroller (changecolorViewController) to another (target is the view parent).
changecolorViewController contain a view that not a fullscreen view only a window

Comment: i update my question with an image to be more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@tamtoum I think i some what understand what you want. So first i am explaining what i understood. You have a view controller named ChangeColorViewController in which there is a view(a small one) which should be displayed on AffairesViewController. Now what i was not able to understand was why you are calling a method from AffairesViewController and then adding the ChangeColorViewController inside that method. Any ways I have a solution for you.

No need to call any method from to add subview, instead make properties for the data which you are passing in the method. Handel that data in ChangeColorViewController's viewDidiLoad(). Make following changes in your code:

```
func clickChangeColor(nomAffaire : String, idEcoute : String, config : ConfigDto ){

    let changeColorVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryBoardIdentifier") as! ChangeColorViewController

    /* pass data via properties here for eg.
       changeColorVC.message = "YourMessage"
       changeColorVC.button = "YourButtonText"
    */

    self.addChildViewController(changeColorVC)
    self.view.addSubView(changeColorVC.view)

}
```

This answer is according to what i understood so far. If you have any more doubts then you may ask here.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: yes you explain  well 
i cant try your solution because here
let changeColorVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryBoardIdentifier") as! ChangeColorViewController

i dont have a StoryBoardIdentifier, its just a xib file that contain a view witch have a file owner viewcontroller

Comment: i just add  the  view on my xib file, that cause me problem with clicking

Comment: i just change to 

 let  changeColorViewControlleree = ChangeColorViewController(nibName:"ChangeColorViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.addChildViewController(changeColorViewControlleree)
        self.view.addSubview(changeColorViewControlleree.view)


and your solution save me thanks

Comment: Hello @tamtoum1987 I didn't see that you have used XIB for the view. Anyways i am happy that my solution helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

If the subview you are adding is outside the bounds of the superview, than no touches will be detected on the subview. Check for this

Answer (score 0):

When you add a view, `userInteraction` is disabled by default. just add `view.userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: But actually it's not disabled by default

Comment: Some views have this disabled by default, such as UIImageView.   The docs for [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled)  says  "Some UIKit subclasses override this property and return a different default value. See the documentation for that class to determine if it returns a different value."